# Openrp 7 tree view and form view for one class at once

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

Please help me with solving above mentioned issue. I have this class named **"allowance_request"** and what I need to do is creating a form view with tree view for the same class. is it possible to do ?

this is basically what I need to do...

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="edit_hr_allowances_request_form">
            <field name="name">hr.allowances.request.form</field>
            <field name="model">allowance.request</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Allocate Allowances" version="7.0" edit="false">
        <sheet>
                <group>
                <group>
                         <field name="employee_id" width="300"  required="1"/>
                         <field name="department_id" width="300"/> 
                </group> 
                </group> 
                <tree string='List'  style="width: 50%%" class="allowance_request">
                <field name='cat_id' string="Category" />       
                <field name='allowance_type' string="Allowance Type"/>  
            </tree>
            </sheet>
            </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Is there any parent - child relation for `allowance_request` ? If yes then it's possible otherwise not possible.

Comment: It's not actually parent-child relationship but one to many. 
One allowance_request can have Many allowance_attendances.